# XCode/gdb loses stack when debugging over calls to dynamic library functions on iOS

Tags: xcode, ios, debugging, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I've got an iOS project that links to an external static library written in C++.  The static library makes calls to functions implemented by libstdc++, which is dynamically linked.  For instance, I call the initialization function for this library (let's call it `foo_init()`) and it immediately calls `setlocale()`.

The static library is compiled with -g, meaning debug symbols are around for me to step into code inside the debugger.  I successfully step into `foo_init()`.  When I attempt to Step Over the call to `setlocale()`, XCode doesn't quite do that.  It ends up in a function called `dyld_stub_setlocale`.  This function is a single `jmp` instruction to perform the dynamic load & function call.

I've tried Stepping Over/In/Out of `dyld_stub_setlocale` but they don't get me where I want, which is back into `foo_init()`.  Step Over and Step In end up in `stub_helpers`, and Step Out acts like continue.  If I try Step Over/In inside `stub_helpers`, XCode single steps and the stack window displaying `foo_init()` changes to `??`.  At this point, the decision tree for stepping in/out kind of explodes so I won't go into further details, but no combinations I've tried end up back to the line after the call to `setlocale`.

I am able to set a breakpoint for the line, hit continue, and have it work, but this is not a scalable solution for debugging a static library with which I am not very familiar.

Note that I tried to find a way to link libstdc++-static instead so I could avoid the dynamic loader issues, but Apple has removed the library from newer SDKs and I don't have the older ones.

Is there a linker or compiler option to make the code easier for the debugger to decipher?